# Usage of verb in past tense

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Being a non native speaker of English I was shocked when one of my friends used this sentence:

> *Did you called me yesterday?*

According to my understanding it should be:

> *Did you call me yesterday?*

Interestingly, [former](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Did%20you%20called%20me%22) gave 193,000,000 results and the [latter](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Did%20you%20called%20me%22#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Did%20you%20call%20me%22&oq=%22Did%20you%20call%20me%22&gs_l=serp.3...70957.71156.0.71542.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.VnCOUO4yl1Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&fp=1fc7e9b832ceaa6b&biw=1366&bih=667) 60,100,000.

Comment: You are correct in understanding the construction is wrong. As far as Google is concerned it does not filter grammatically right or wrong constructs. So don't worry about it.

Comment: yes your understanding is perfect "Did you call me yesterday?" should be the right sentence

Comment: What @Mistu4u said. But you might want to try Google ***Books*** for a better idea of what forms are acceptable enough to actually make it into print. There, you'll find [232,000](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Did+you+call+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) hits for "Did you call me". But "Did you ***called*** me" gets [no results worth mentioning](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Did+you+called+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: ...also note that your Google search term didn't include the word "yesterday", which is important for removing huge numbers of irrelevant hits - such as *"You insulted me!"* *"No I didn't!"* *"Yes you **did! You called me** a redneck!"* If you *do* include "yesterday", you still get almost 5,000,000 hits for "call", but only 8 for "called". Case closed.